# How to prohibit calling of actions based upon user login status in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to call some actions only when user is logged in.
How to do it without checking the user login status every time?

Comment: You need to set up [access control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a `behaviors()` method to your controller such as :

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The roles defined above are `@` for all users that are logged in and `?` for all users that aren't logged in. In your case you will be interrested in setting the role to `@`.

You can of course replace these with any rbac roles/permissions.
[Here's more information on authorization from the Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)